# 'Camera' does not name a type BB10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

```
#ifndef CAMERAHANDLER_H_
#define CAMERAHANDLER_H_
#include <QtCore/QObject>


class CameraHandler: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //… constructor destructor etc
    void setupControls(const QString &camName, const QString &vfButtonName);
    Q_INVOKABLE void camerastart();
    Q_INVOKABLE void camerastop();
    private slots:
    void onOpenSuccess(); //when camera is opened successfully
    void onShutterFired(); //when we get shutterfired event
    void onButtonClick(); //when the button is clicked
    void onStopVfSuccess(); //when viewfinder has been stopped
    void onStartVfSuccess(); //when viewfinder has been started

    private:
    Camera* m_camera;
    Button* m_camButton;
    bool m_ViewfinderOn;
    bool m_cameraopen;
    //const bb::cascades::AbstractPane *m_abstractPane;
};

#endif /* CAMERAHANDLER_H_ */
```

I have file Camerahandler.h file in src folder Cascades Framework to develop BB10 app.

But i receive error "'Camera' does not name a type" & "'Button' does not name a 
 type". Please help me fix!

Answer (score 0):

How about if you add these two?

```
#include <bb/cascades/multimedia/Camera>
#include <bb/cascades/Button>
```

Comment: I add 2 line but i have new errror 'Camera' does not name a type